# Enable sgml-close-tag while in js-jsx-mode

Tags: emacs

My GNU Emacs version is 27.2.

I have a React file with js-jsx-mode active `(JavaScript[JSX])`.

```
const App = () => {

return (
  <div className="container">
    My Content
```

I can close the `<div>` after "My Content" quickly with `M-x sgml-close-tag`, and have globally set `C-/` to do so.

I have noticed that switching to SGML-mode (with `M-x sgml-mode`), then switching back to `js-jsx-mode` will always allow me to execute `sgml-close-tag`.

Sometimes, on startup (or upon loading the JS file), the underlying sgml-mode is automatically loaded, and other times, I get the error:

`Wrong type argument: commandp, sgml-close-tag`.

When I get this error, I can switch to sgml-mode and back, and the function will work.

However, I would like to consistently load whatever it is in `sgml-mode` that will allow me to run `sgml-close-tag` while in `js-jsx-mode`, without having to do the mode switching.

What is the best way to make sure `sgml-close-tag` will be available in `js-jsx-mode`? Or is there another function with the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing `js-mode-hook`, calling sgml-mode and then js-jsx-mode, but this led to infinite recursion.

A hack that works is to use a third (unused) mode in .emacs as a mechanism to switch to sgml-mode, and then to js-jsx-mode. The third mode I chose is html-mode:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . html-mode))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (auto-complete-mode 1)
        (sgml-mode)
        (js-jsx-mode)))
```

There are many modes that I don't use, and the procedure above will make that mode inaccessible.